# How to draw a rectangle manually in html without canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

[What I mean is understood better in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3IFX.gif)

In the given photo, I used canvas for drawings; however, I would like to do it by an another way because I want to created rectangles be draggable and give ids to created rectangles. For example, If I used div instead of canvas, I could not manually draw the rectangles like in the photo. Maybe, there is a way but I don't know it. When I searched this subject, most of the people use paper.js, etc. but it is just useful in resize or drag&drop; therefore, I did not want to use these.

```js
function lettersOnly(input) {
  var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //Canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //Variables
  var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
  var canvasx = canvasOffset.left;
  var canvasy = canvasOffset.top;
  var last_mousex = 0;
  var last_mousey = 0;
  var mousex = 0;
  var mousey = 0;
  var mousedown = false;
  var shapes = [];
  var width;
  var height;
  // make var col a global variable
  var col = "black";
  var ad = "";

  //Mousedown
  $(canvas).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
    last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
    mousedown = true;
  });

  //Mouseup
  $(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    const lastPos = {
      lastMouseX: last_mousex,
      lastMouseY: last_mousey,
      rectWidth: width,
      rectHeight: height,
      // save the color of the rect
      color: col,
      name: ad
    };
    shapes.push(lastPos);
    mousedown = false;
  });

  //Mousemove
  $(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);

    if (mousedown) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      width = mousex - last_mousex;
      height = mousey - last_mousey;
      col = $("#color").val();
      ad = $("#name").val();
      if (shapes.length > 0) {
        for (var i in shapes) {
          // for every shape in the shapes array beginPath
          ctx.beginPath();
          //set the color of the stroke
          ctx.strokeStyle = shapes[i].color;
          //draw the rect
          ctx.rect(shapes[i].lastMouseX, shapes[i].lastMouseY, shapes[i].rectWidth, shapes[i].rectHeight);
          ctx.fillText(shapes[i].name, shapes[i].rectWidth - shapes[i].lastMouseX, shapes[i].rectHeight - shapes[i].lastMouseY);
          ctx.stroke();

        }
      }
      //for the new rect beginPath
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(last_mousex, last_mousey, width, height);
      ctx.strokeStyle = col;
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.fillText(ad, 100, 100);
      ctx.stroke();

    }
    $('#output').html('Current Coordinate: ' + mousex + ', ' + mousey + '<br/>Last Coordinate: ' + last_mousex + ', ' + last_mousey);

  });
});
```

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#color {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 45%;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#name {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 45%;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.submit {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-image: url("kroki2v3.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 210;
  margin-top: 160;
  position: static;
  display: block;
}

#output {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 19%;
  left: 46%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="color" style="margin-top: 70px" placeholder="Color" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" style="margin-top: 100px;" placeholder="Department Name" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-top: 130px;" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="">Project</a>
    <a href="https://pavotek.com.tr/iletisim/">Contact</a>
    <a href="https://pavotek.com.tr/biz_kimiz/">About</a>
  </div>

  <div id="container" style="display: none;"><img src="kroki2v3.png" id="img01" alt="" style="display: none;"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="520"></canvas>
  <div id="output"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your photo is **403 Forbidden** for me

Comment: Please embed the photo instead of linking to it.

Comment: Well, I can't see your image as others have noted. But... a `div` is a rectangle AND it can have an id and be draggable via javascript.

Comment: I edited the question with embedded photo; but if I want to open it, it gives me an error. I wish, you could open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? When you say "draw", this is what I imagined.

You need to find the mouse position in the `mousedown` function and in the `mousemove` function, then subtract the mousedown x and y position from the mousemove x and y position to set the width and height.

You also need to set a variable to tell whether or not the mouse is actually down while moving the mouse to ensure a div isn't "drawn" without knowledge.

Once you "mouseup" you can set your draggable / resizable functions to be used.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/8cpqntjh/);

```js
$(function() {
  var widget;
  var x;
  var y;
  var finX;
  var finY;
  var ismousedown = false;
  $(document).on({
    mousedown: function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).attr('class') == 'wrapper') {
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;
        $('body').append('<div class="widget" style="top:' + y + 'px; left: ' + x + 'px;"></div>');
        widget = $('.widget').last();
        ismousedown = true;
      }
    },
    mousemove: function(event) {
      if (ismousedown == true) {
        finX = event.pageX;
        finY = event.pageY;
        widget.width(finX - x);
        widget.height(finY - y);
        widget.css({
          'width': (finX - x) + '!important',
          'height': (finY - y) + '!important',
          'display': 'block',
          'border': '2px dashed #ccc'
        });
      }
    },
    mouseup: function(event) {
      ismousedown = false;
      widget.css({
        'background': '#222',
        'border': '0',
        'cursor': 'move'
      });
      initDraggable();
    }

  });

  // in case you need to reinitialize later.
  function initDraggable() {
    $('.widget').draggable({});
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.widget {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: @Souleste_ Thank you for your response. This is almost what I want to do; however, I want this grids to be very small so that a user could do what he/she want. Therefore, I will edit your code for small grids and small steps. Maybe, I can delete this grids but their function will become same.

Comment: @UtkuDemir If you are speaking about the "grid" option on my codepen, then yes, you can absolutely edit that. The steps are by pixels, so you can make it as small as 1 pixel if you want. I prefer to use the grid option so that the widgets are always in a "perfect" position. Have a look at jQuery UI draggable for more options: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/